# Motor encoder and interrupts

Tags: interrupt, rotary-encoder, raspberrypi-pico

I'm trying to write motor controller for automated blinds using Raspberry Pi Pico with [arduino-pico](https://github.com/earlephilhower/arduino-pico).
My problem is that I can't seem to get a consistent result from motor encoders.

In my `setup` function I attach the interrupt:

```
void motor0Enc1handler() {
  motor0.handleEnc1();
}

void setup() {
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(motor0.getEnc1()), motor0Enc1handler, RISING);
}
```

`Motor` is a class with the following interrupt processing code:

```
int Motor::getEnc1() {
  return _enc1;
}
void Motor::handleEnc1() {
  // debug only
  if (digitalRead(_enc1) != HIGH) {
    _false_triggers++;
  }

  if (digitalRead(_enc2) == HIGH) {
    // debug only
    if (!_going_down) {
      _direction_changes++;
    }
    _going_down = true;

    _pos = _isLeft ? _pos - 1 : _pos + 1;
  } else {
    // debug only
    if (_going_down) {
      _direction_changes++;
    }
    _going_down = false;

    _pos = _isLeft ? _pos + 1 : _pos - 1;
  }
}
```

Interrupt is attached to one of the hall effect sensors on the motor. It has 2 sensors set an angle, so the direction of the motor can be determined.
For example, when `_enc1` is `HIGH` and `_enc2` is low at the same time it means that the motor is moving in one direction, when `_enc2` is also high it moves in the opposite direction.
[Here](https://support.maxongroup.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005962273-Encoder-channels-A-and-B-phase-shift-and-direction-of-rotation) is much better explanation of this.
The main point is that the timing is extremely important to properly calculate the number of rotations the motor made.

For example, if `handleEnc1` is delayed the motor would have slightly moved already and `digitalRead(_enc2)` will return incorrect value.

In my interrupt I've set up a few debugging variables:
`_false_triggers` is incremented when `handleEnc1` is triggered, but when trying to read the same pin value it returns unexpected result. For example, `handleEnc1` is triggered on `RISING`, so I would expect the pin value to be `HIGH`. If it's not high, it means that the interrupt was delayed and the hall effect sensor is not reporting a different value, because the motor shaft has rotated.
`_direction_changes` is incremented when motor is supposed to be moving in a single direction, so I would expect `digitalRead(_enc2) == HIGH` to always be `true` or `false` depending on the direction. If the motor keeps turning in the same direction it should never be incremented.

My hardware setup is:
Raspberry Pi Pico (`_enc1` is pin `20`, `_enc2` is pin `21`).
Motor is `JGA25-370` with encoders.
Interrupts are triggered at about 2 interrupts per millisecond.

What happens is that I get non-zero `_direction_changes` and `_false_triggers` during normal operation:

- start the motor to go in a single direction
- serial print direction changes and false triggers from time to time
- write current motor position into a file with LittleFS in flash memory.

In this case I get about `15-20` `_direction_changes` per 10000 steps and around `10` `_false_triggers`.
When I disable writing of motor position into a flash file it get less `_direction_changes` (around 10) and `_false_triggers` drops to zero, which is an improvement and it proves that the code is susceptible to competing interrupts (I imagine writing to file system or serial uses interrupts).
However, this is not ideal, since I need to use SPI as well to talk via nRF24l01 and I also need to persist current motor position periodically in case of a power loss.
Also, I don't want to have a position drift for my automated blinds, even though it's relatively small, but it will compound over time.

Am I not using interrupts correctly encoders?
Is there a better way to approach this?
I was thinking about attaching interrupts to both `_enc1` and `enc2` and push events into a queue and then process it in the main code, but I don't think it's going to work. I can only attach interrupts to either `FALLING` or `RISING` so I would be able to detect pulses in a single direction, if I attach interrupts to `CHANGE` it would mean I'd have to read pin value from within interrupt which is prone to the same issue that I'm already experiencing.

I guess my main problem is that I feel like I shouldn't be having this problem. I only have 2 pulses per millisecond, so it's not that many. Interrupt code is not doing much (unless I'm not supposed to do `digitalRead` in an interrupt). So I feel like there should be a reliable way to maintain motor position even if there is other stuff going on in the application.

The full code is [here](https://github.com/Leonti/roller-blinds-controller/blob/5e23abdf5bd3ab8ca2ab23c6e84c46d3b1650210/firmware/src/main.cpp) in case it's helpful.

Comment: "Am I not using interrupts correctly encoders"? I would suggest that you read Nick Gammon's [Interrupt](https://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts) to understand the "do and don't of interrupt" first. I would also suggest you move most of the code in your `Motor::Motor()` construct to `Motor::begin()` as when you instantiating an instance of Motor object before the `setup()`, many of the peripherals might not be ready, or available yet.

Comment: Thanks!
I've read the post and so far other than not using `volatile` it seems like I'm not violating any rules of interrupts. That post even mentioned reading and writing to pins.
Since it's Raspberry Pi Pico I was able to use PIO to read interrupts (found a project on Github) which seems to have improved things, but I'd still like to to understand why it's not reliable the way I've implemented it.
Thanks for the advice about moving `Motor::begin()` into `setup`, it's a good point.